# Solaris SPARC: How to see what hanging process is doing?

Tags: c, solaris

I have a process that seems to be hanging on solaris, I have tried to attach to the process using GDB to see what it is doing but no luck.

There is no error from what I can see, it is just sitting there...

Are there any other tools or techniques I can use to see what the process is stuck on?

Thanks for the help

Lynton

Comment: Why GDB couldn't attach to the process?

Answer (score 4):

`pstack <pid>` will print you what all the threads within this process are doing (full stack traces, including function names, if your binary is not stripped.

`truss` is Linux's `strace` equivalent. It will show all the system calls that the process is doing. It might help you in debugging.

DTrace is a great debugging swiss-army-knife that can show you pretty much anything you can think of. The downside is that it needs to be run with root permissions on a global zone. It takes some time to learn, but it's time well worth spending.

Answer (score 0):

Use powerful dtrace facility.
Here the short [introduction](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/DTrace/User+Process+Tracing) how to trace user processes.